# Unable to create custom msg lbl with chat bubble in chat table view. (all programmatically)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

1. I have 1 class creating bezier bubble (working)
2. In tableviewcell class I am creating msg label programmatically using function
3. I use that function in view controller with table view
4. Images below are from same code.
5. Array used for data is ["a","aa","aaa","aaaa","aaaaa"]

Issue = The msg label is not showing/ being created

I have given all required things. The function visible in code is being directly called in tableview's cellforrowat function.

Image 1 = [Hierarchy view 1 after clicking button] (https://ibb.co/QfvsV3C)
Image 2 = [Hierarchy view 2 before clicking button] (https://ibb.co/L0pz2kz)

msg lbl code :

```
func drawMsgLbl(text: String)
{
    //var msg                 =   UILabel()
    //msg                     =   UILabel()
    //msg?.lineBreakMode      =   .byWordWrapping
    msg.numberOfLines       =   0
    msg.font                =   UIFont.init(name: "Avenir", size: 20)
    msg.text                =   text
    let txtWidth            =   text.size(OfFont: msg.font)
    msg.textColor           =   .black
    msg.backgroundColor     =   .yellow
//        msg.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: msg.intrinsicContentSize.width, height: msg.intrinsicContentSize.height)

    let constraintRect = CGSize(width: (0.66 * self.frame.width),
                                height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
    let boundingBox = text.boundingRect(with: constraintRect,
                                        options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin,
                                        attributes: [.font: msg.font],
                                        context: nil)
    msg.frame.size = CGSize(width: ceil(boundingBox.width),
                             height: ceil(boundingBox.height))

    print("Bounnding Width = \(boundingBox.width)")
    print("msgIntrinsicWidth = \(msg.intrinsicContentSize.width)")
    print("Text Width = \(txtWidth)")
    print(text)


    msg.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: (self.frame.size.width)-((msg.frame.size.width))-20, y: (self.frame.height)+10)
    //msg?.center = self.center

    let bubbleSize = CGSize(width: ((msg.frame.size.width)+30), height: ((msg.frame.size.height)+20))

    let incomingBubblee = incomingBubble()
    let outgoingBubblee = outgoingBubble()

    outgoingBubblee.frame.size = bubbleSize
    outgoingBubblee.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: (frame.size.width)-((msg.frame.size.width))-30, y: frame.size.height)
    outgoingBubblee.backgroundColor = .clear

    self.addSubview(outgoingBubblee)
    self.addSubview(msg)
    self.backgroundColor = .gray
}
```

I want to generate a msg label with width and height depending upon the text it has with a Bezier path that is being used (its code is placed separately, and the code is working fine)

Comment: Read up on how to use auto-layout and constraints. Will make it much easier - both to accomplish what you're trying to do as well as figuring out what's not working right.

Comment: @DonMag I am creating everything programatically. So that you just have to set the class for a UIView and it will create everything for you according to your data.

Comment: Programmatically or not... you'll still be much better off using auto-layout. Show an image of how you *want* your cell to look.

Comment: I want it to be like WhatsApp / Viber / iMessage msg bubble

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a very simple example, using auto-layout constraints to allow the cells / rows to auto-size their heights.

All via code - no `@IBOutlets` or prototype cells - so just assign a `UITableViewController` to this class (`ChatBubbleTestTableViewController`)

```
// simple "Message" struct
struct MyMessage {
    var incoming: Bool = false
    var message: String = ""
}

class ChatBubbleView: UIView {

    let bubbleLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    let chatLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.numberOfLines = 0
        v.text = "Sample text"
        return v
    }()

    // if it's an incoming message, background will be gray and bubble left-aligned
    // otherwise background will be green and bubble right-alinged
    var incoming = false

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() -> Void {

        // add the bubble layer
        layer.addSublayer(bubbleLayer)

        // add the label
        addSubview(chatLabel)

        // constrain the label with 12-pts padding on all 4 sides
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            chatLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 12.0),
            chatLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -12.0),
            chatLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 12.0),
            chatLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -12.0),
            ])

    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        let width = bounds.size.width
        let height = bounds.size.height

        let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()

        // NOTE: this bezier path is from
        // https://medium.com/@dima_nikolaev/creating-a-chat-bubble-which-looks-like-a-chat-bubble-in-imessage-the-advanced-way-2d7497d600ba
        if incoming {
            bezierPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 22, y: height))
            bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: width - 17, y: height))
            bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: width, y: height - 17), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: width - 7.61, y: height), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: width, y: height - 7.61))
            bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: width, y: 17))
            bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: width - 17, y: 0), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: width, y: 7.61), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: width - 7.61, y: 0))
            bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 21, y: 0))
            bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 4, y: 17), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 11.61, y: 0), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 4, y: 7.61))
            bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 4, y: height - 11))
            bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: height), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 4, y: height - 1), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 0, y: height))
            bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: -0.05, y: height - 0.01))
            bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 11.04, y: height - 4.04), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 4.07, y: height + 0.43), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 8.16, y: height - 1.06))
            bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 22, y: height), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 16, y: height), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 19, y: height))
            bezierPath.close()
        } else {
            bezierPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: width - 22, y: height))
            bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 17, y: height))
            bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: height - 17), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 7.61, y: height), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 0, y: height - 7.61))
            bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 17))
            bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 17, y: 0), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 7.61), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 7.61, y: 0))
            bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: width - 21, y: 0))
            bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: width - 4, y: 17), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: width - 11.61, y: 0), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: width - 4, y: 7.61))
            bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: width - 4, y: height - 11))
            bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: width, y: height), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: width - 4, y: height - 1), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: width, y: height))
            bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: width + 0.05, y: height - 0.01))
            bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: width - 11.04, y: height - 4.04), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: width - 4.07, y: height + 0.43), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: width - 8.16, y: height - 1.06))
            bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: width - 22, y: height), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: width - 16, y: height), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: width - 19, y: height))
            bezierPath.close()
        }

        bubbleLayer.fillColor = incoming ? UIColor(white: 0.90, alpha: 1.0).cgColor : UIColor.green.cgColor

        bubbleLayer.path = bezierPath.cgPath

    }
}

class ChatCell: UITableViewCell {

    let bubbleView: ChatBubbleView = {
        let v = ChatBubbleView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()

    var leadingOrTrailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint()

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() -> Void {

        // add the bubble view
        contentView.addSubview(bubbleView)

        // constrain top / bottom with 12-pts padding
        // constrain width to lessThanOrEqualTo 2/3rds (66%) of the width of the cell
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            bubbleView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 12.0),
            bubbleView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -12.0),
            bubbleView.widthAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: contentView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.66),
            ])

    }

    func setData(_ message: MyMessage) -> Void {

        // set the label text
        bubbleView.chatLabel.text = message.message

        // tell the bubble view whether it's an incoming or outgoing message
        bubbleView.incoming = message.incoming

        // left- or right-align the bubble view, based on incoming or outgoing
        leadingOrTrailingConstraint.isActive = false
        if message.incoming {
            leadingOrTrailingConstraint = bubbleView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 12.0)
        } else {
            leadingOrTrailingConstraint = bubbleView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -12.0)
        }
        leadingOrTrailingConstraint.isActive = true
    }

}

class ChatBubbleTestTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    let theData: [MyMessage] = [
        MyMessage(incoming: false, message: "A short message."),
        MyMessage(incoming: true, message: "A medium length message, longer than short."),
        MyMessage(incoming: false, message: "A long message. This one should be long enough to wrap onto multiple lines, showing that this message bubble cell will auto-size itself to the message content."),
        MyMessage(incoming: true, message: "Another short message."),
        MyMessage(incoming: false, message: "Another medium length message, longer than short."),
        MyMessage(incoming: true, message: "Another long message. This one should be long enough to wrap onto multiple lines, showing that this message bubble cell will auto-size itself to the message content."),
    ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.register(ChatCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "ChatCell")
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return theData.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ChatCell", for: indexPath) as! ChatCell
        cell.setData(theData[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }

}
```

The result:

[image]

and note that it auto-sizes when the cell changes size (such as when you rotate the device):

[image]

---

**EDIT**

The problem with your code...

In `ChatCell.swift`, you have:

```
func commonInit()
{
    contentView.addSubview(bubbleView)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        bubbleView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 12.0),
        bubbleView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -12.0),
        bubbleView.widthAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: contentView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.66)
        ])
}
```

`bubbleView` needs to be constrained to the cell's `contentView`:

```
func commonInit()
{
    contentView.addSubview(bubbleView)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        bubbleView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 12.0),
        bubbleView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -12.0),
        bubbleView.widthAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: contentView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.66)
        ])
}
```

---

**EDIT 2**

The most straight-forward way to change the bubble background colors...

In `ChatBubbleView` class, remove this line (at the end of `layoutSubviews()`:

```
bubbleLayer.fillColor = isIncoming ? UIColor(white: 0.90, alpha: 1.0).cgColor : UIColor.green.cgColor
```

In `ChatCell` class, add two properties:

```
var incomingColor: UIColor = UIColor(white: 0.90, alpha: 1.0)
var outgoingColor: UIColor = UIColor.green
```

Those will be your "default" colors.

Also in `ChatCell` class, in `setData()`, add this line:

```
    bubbleView.bubbleLayer.fillColor = message.incoming ? incomingColor.cgColor : outgoingColor.cgColor
```

Then, in `TestVC` in `cellForRowAt`, you can do this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell",for: indexPath) as! ChatCell

    cell.incomingColor = .cyan
    cell.outgoingColor = .yellow

    cell.setData(theData[indexPath.row])

    return cell
}
```

I'll leave it up to you as to how you want to implement color selection by the user.

Comment: That was VERY helpful .... but I have 2 more issues with this ....

(1). How are you getting your UITableView HeightForRow ?   UITableView.AutomaticDimension is not working for me here. As you can see in this image : h t t p : // tinyimg.io/i/R7xXSFM.png



(2). Trying to give @IBInspectable to that bubble code from Medium seems to be not working ... it just changes the color to black if I try to give it color using a variable from it.

Comment: 1) When using auto-layout, you do ***NOT*** need `heightForRowAt`. You let auto-layout *automatically* determine the row height, based on the constraints you've set up (see my example code). 2) Remove the term `@IBInspectable` from your mind - it has **nothing** to do with this. Where are you trying to change the colors? Do you want the ability to specify the bubble background color at run-time? So you might have cyan, yellow, gray, orange, etc chat bubbles?

Comment: 1. Okay, but as soon as i remove heightforrowat function it is not showing any text like just the little are of top of the bubble like 30-40 constant value height for each row.

2. yes i want the ability to specify bubble background color @ run-time like whatever color they want you know like a Theme setter (that u can change from some settings or somewhere)

Comment: 1) Are you using the example code I posted? Because that code handles the row heights correctly. If not, compare what you've done that is different to what I did. 2) I'll edit the sample code to show how to set the background colors at run-time.

Comment: There is only 1 change that I am doing, instead of making class ChatBubbleTestTableViewController: UITableViewController ... I have given the tableviewcontroller and made an outlet for it.
And then I'm writing the code as its extension.
for cellforrow / numberofrowsinsection etc and the viewdidload tableview.register also is in that UIViewController with tableviewcontroller only

Comment: It shouldn't matter if it's a `UITableViewController` or a `UIViewController` with a table view as a subview. Post your code (use pastebin or GitHub) and I'll see what's going on.

Comment: Here's the paste bin link : h t t p s : // pastebin.com/XdmAjv6e ..... these are the files being used. Plus ... I have generated 1 Prototype cell with identifier "ChatCell" as in ur code and given that cell ChatCell class.  Thats all.

If you want I can upload the test project on GitHub too if this doesn't help.

Comment: In your pastebin code, you have implemented `heightForRowAt` with `return 300`. That means every row will be 300-pts in height. Delete that entire `heightForRowAt`  function.

Comment: That is for testing ... without that i get empty squished bubbles with i guess default ? 30-40 height ? in each row without any text

Sorry was publishing test repository so u can check yourself what I mean
h t t p s : // github.com/FahadSaleem907/testChatApp

Comment: Files Used = Controllers -> TestVC ....... Utilities -> ChatBubbleView ..... Utilities -> ChatCell ....

Comment: See the **EDIT** at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Note: since you are registering the `ChatCell` class for reuse via code, you do **not** need a prototype cell in your Storyboard.

Comment: that worked like a charm! I was missing out the contentView for bubble to be placed on. ty
What about the color change for bubble on runtime ... or using some setting/theme option ?

Comment: I added an **EDIT 2** to my answer, showing you one way to handle changing the bubble background colors. That's getting beyond the scope of your question, though, so I'll let you work ahead from here.